# Different Styles & Switching themes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

OK, here's my 2-fold issue :

**A)**

While developing I need to be able to **switch from Dark to Light theme, without having to run the app in the Emulator** - is that possible? And if so, how?

**B)**

Regarding colors/etc of my various controls I usually use *built-in* standard colors (like `Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"`).

Now what if I want to **create a custom style** and want to - let's say - set the `Foreground` to *gray* (while using Light theme) and to *orangered* (while using Dark theme) - how should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) It's possible to use the designer in Visual Studio to see how a page will look under different  theme/accent combinations. Use the Device Windows (under the "DESIGN" menu). A similar option also exists in Blend.

[image: Visual Studio Device Window]

B) You can do this with converters but I like to make my own resource for things like this. Just create a class like this:

```
public class MyColorResource
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The resource name - as it can be referenced by within the app
    /// </summary>
    private const string ResourceName = "MyColorResource";

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MyColorResource"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MyColorResource()
    {
        try
        {
            // This doesn't work in the designer - so don't even try
            if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Make sure we don't try and add the resource more than once - would happen if referenced on multiple pages or in app and page(s)
            if (!Application.Current.Resources.Contains(ResourceName))
            {
                if (Visibility.Visible == (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"])
                {
                    Application.Current.Resources.Add(ResourceName, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Resources.Add(ResourceName, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something went wrong - ask for your money back");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your app make a reference to it (either in App.xaml or your main page is normally good)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:MyColorResource x:Key="AnythingAsNotActuallyUsed" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then you can use it in XAML like any other resource:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource MyColorResource}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
```